# Nginx - Php-Fpm - PDO_OCI?

Tags: php, pdo, oracle-call-interface

today i tried to install nginx with php-fpm, here all right! after i compiled pdo_oci but when i try to execute pdo on the project i receive this error from nginx's log:

> recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, >client: 127.0.0.1, server: simpletest.smartcrew.local, request: "GET /index.php?>r=gii/model/index HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: >"simpletest.smartcrew.local

from php-fpm's log

> WARNING: [pool www] child 5887 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 536.033550 seconds from start

I tried to execute the same pdo_oci compiled module  with apache and php-cli and i don't have any issue.

Someone could help me. :)

Thanks a lot to all!

Comment: Can you show your nginx.conf ? P.S. I see this question is 2 years old and seems no longer actual :)